# Эффект рождественских огней

Tags: css, css3, html5, анимация

Я пытаюсь создать рождественские огни (в январе), используя CSS  `-webkit-animation` свойства.

Для этого я использую это изображение:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я пробовал:

```
@-webkit-keyframes lights {
    0% {
        background-position:0px;
    } 100% {
        background-position:0 -69px;
    }
}

#lights {
    width:100%;
    height:69px;
    background:url(https://mysterybrand.net/assets/images/new-year/live-drop-gardland.png);
    -webkit-animation: lights 1s infinite;
}
```

Чего я хочу добиться: я хочу постоянно менять `background position`, чтобы казалось, что свет выключается и включается.

Почему мой код не меняет `background position`, а анимирует изображение?

Надеюсь, кто-нибудь может мне помочь.

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/54160653/7394871

Comment: Вот есть красивая [гирлянда](https://codepen.io/Imapo/pen/jAxpYv)

Answer (score 5):

Вы можете рассмотреть `steps()`<sup>**1**</sup>, чтобы получить необходимый эффект, и отрегулировать позиции, как показано ниже.

Обратите внимание на начальное значение, потому что `0` не совпадает с `0 0`:

```css
@keyframes lights {
    0% {
       /*Two zeros, not one !!*/
       /*[0] is equivalent to [0 50%] and will create a different animation */
        background-position:0 0; 
    } 
    100% {
        background-position:0 -138px;
    }
}

#lights {
    height:69px;
    background:url(https://mysterybrand.net/assets/images/new-year/live-drop-gardland.png);
    animation: lights 1s infinite steps(2);
}
```

```html
<div id="lights"></div>
```

Или сделайте это так:

```css
@keyframes lights {
    0%,50% {
        background-position:0 0; /*Two zeros, not one !!*/
    } 
    50.1%,100% {
        background-position:0 -69px;
    }
}

#lights {
    height:69px;
    background:url(https://mysterybrand.net/assets/images/new-year/live-drop-gardland.png);
    animation: lights 1s infinite;
}
```

```html
<div id="lights"></div>
```

Подробнее о том, как использовать `steps()`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51843473/8620333

Comment: Просто и красиво :)

Comment: @VerNick бери на вооружение к Новогоднему конкурсу. Спрайт лампочек можно самому нарисовать и сделать, что-нибудь посложнее.

Comment: Кстати да, появилась идея добавить это к моей ёлочке :)

Comment: Добавил, но другую, с этой не получалось (